# build gdb and gdbserver for android

Tags: gdb, gdbserver, android-debugging

I'm working on 64 bit linux, need to build *gdbserver* for my aarch64 Android phone.There is prebuilt *gdbserver* in NDK, but it uses the python in NDK package, not using my system python, I can't install other python plugins.

How to find which `--target` and `--host` parameter is required for `./configure`? I tried the `--help`, and google like "build gdbserver aarch64" or "gdbserver configure android",  but did't find any answer for aarch64 Android.

For *gdb* I can use `./configure --enable-targets=all`, but what for `gdbserver`? Is there any "List" for all the available parameters?

Here's how I tried to build *gdbserver*

1. downloaded the [gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major-x86_64-linux](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm/downloads) package, decompress and add it to PATH, add environment variable `CC=arm-none-eabi-gcc`, `CXX=arm-none-eabi-g++`, make the executable available in PATH
2. I tried all of these:

```
    ../configure  
    ../configure --host=aarch64-linux             --target=aarch64-linux-androideabi
    ../configure --host=aarch64-linux-androideabi --target=aarch64-linux
    ../configure --host=aarch64-linux-androideabi --target=aarch64-linux-androideabi
```

3. make, which results in:

```
    ...
    make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
    make[3]: Leaving directory '/opt/gdb-9.1/gdb/gdbserver/build/build-libiberty-gdbserver/testsuite'
    make[2]: Leaving directory '/opt/gdb-9.1/gdb/gdbserver/build/build-libiberty-gdbserver'
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/gdb-9.1/gdb/gdbserver/build'
    make: *** No rule to make target '../alloc.c'.  Stop.
```

```
also tried:
```

```
    make CC=arm-none-eabi-gcc CXX=arm-none-eabi-g++
    or CC=aarch64-linux-android28-clang CXX=aarch64-linux-android28-clang++
```

```
But same result.
```

Comment: You do understand that the `gdbserver` runs on the target platform, and must be built with the compiler targeting Android / aarch64, right? Using `CC=... CXX=... ./configure && make` should be enough.

Comment: @EmployedRussian Hi, I tried your tip, but still no luck, post updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got answer from somewhere else, put here in case who wants do the same.

1. Download gdb source code:

```
   wget ftp://sourceware.org/pub/gdb/releases/gdb-9.1.tar.gz
```

2. Extract file:

```
 tar xzvf gdb-9.1.tar.gz
```

3. Move into source folder

```
 cd gdb-9.1
```

4. Edit file gdb/gdbserver/linux-low.c:

- 4.1. Add two lines : Line 107 & Line 122 with the content below

```
#define HAVE_ELF32_AUXV_T  //  Line 107 (Added)
#ifndef HAVE_ELF32_AUXV_T

#define HAVE_ELF64_AUXV_T // Line 122 (Added)
#ifndef HAVE_ELF64_AUXV_T
```

This modification is neccessary to build Android, since Android system libraries already define  struct Elf32_auxv_t and Elf64_auxv_t .(Please see this for detail: https://github.com/android/ndk/issues/1008)

- 4.2. Modify function `linux_request_interrupt`:

```
static void
linux_request_interrupt (void)
 {
   /* .... */
-  kill (-signal_pid, SIGINT); // replace this line with next 3 lines
+  int r = kill (-signal_pid, SIGINT);
+  if (r != 0)
+      kill (signal_pid, SIGINT);
 }
```

This fixes bug "gdbserver not handling `Ctrl+C`", detail at:  https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=18772

5. Build gdb for linux:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential \
  gcc g++ make autogen m4 \
  bison gettext libpython-dev

mkdir build-linux

cd build-linux/

../configure --enable-targets=all --with-python=/usr/bin/python

make -j4

sudo make install
```

6. Build gdbserver for android:

- 6.1.  Download android-sdk

```
cd ~

mkdir android

cd android

wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-6200805_latest.zip

unzip commandlinetools-linux-6200805_latest.zip

export PATH=$PATH:~/android/tools/bin
```

- 6.2. Install Ndk

```
sdkmanager --install "ndk;21.0.6113669" --sdk_root=.
```

- 6.3.  Create standalone toolchain for NDK

```
cd ~/android/ndk/21.0.6113669/

./build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh \ 
--toolchain=aarch64-linux-android-4.9 \
--install-dir=~/android/ndk_21
```

This step create the standalone toolchain at: ~/android/ndk_21

- 6.4. Configure and build gdbserver for android

```
cd ~/gdb-9.1

mkdir build-android

cd build-android

export PATH=$PATH:~/android/ndk_21/bin

CC=aarch64-linux-android-gcc ../configure \
    --target=aarch64-linux-android \
    --host=aarch64-linux-android \
     LDFLAGS="-static-libstdc++"

make -j4
```

If get error related to "source-highlight", add `--disable-source-highlight` to the `configure` flag.

After build finishes, *gdbserver* is located at: gdb/gdbserver/gdbserver

Comment: Cool! If I ever need to build gdbserver myself in the future, I know where to find out how :-)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get this is through the NDK that comes with the Android SDK, e.g., with Android Studio. Got to the NDK in the Android SDK and navigate to `ndk-bundle/prebuilt/android-arm64/gdbserver/gdbserver` ; that will give you a prebuilt gdbserver executable for aarch64 (arm64). You'll find other prebuilt gdbserver executables in ndk-bundle/prebuilt also, besides for aarch64.

Comment: Thanks. I missed the *why* in the post, NDK's prebuilt uses its own python, not system pthon. I cannot install plugin with `pip` to it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I guess also if you want to modify the gdbserver source code ..

Answer (score 0):

To install gdb in termux you can simply run:

```
pkg install gdb
```

which will install gdb and gdbserver